# How to add a Round rect button outside of a cell in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do I add a round rect button outside of a cell in a UITableView?

For example :

[image]

The "Other","home" & "home" fields are all independent cells.

What I am trying to achieve is the ability to add buttons such as the "Text Message","Share Contact" & "Add to favorites" shown above.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: How about creating a custom cell with those buttons in it ?

Comment: Are you sure these are table view cells? They look like UIButtons with type UIButtonTypeRoundedRect to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a footer (or header) to the appropriate section.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,x,x,x)];

    UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,x,x,x);
    [yourButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [yourView addSubview:yourButton];

    return yourView;
}
```

Comment: The appropriate cell? I think you mean section.

Comment: @max_ I did, edited to reflect that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two options within regular `UITableViews.`

1. It is a cell with transparent background of the content view and of the cell itself.
2. It is a section header. Noting stops you from inventing a new section exactly there, a section with 0 rows even. And you overwrite the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method and provide an appropriate header with buttond and whatever you like. This one, too, shold have a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom cell with a transparent background and you can add those buttons on it. Alternatively, you could use the section footer to do pretty much the same.